# Can I make Visual Studio 2017 load symbols for release versions

Tags: visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging

Starting with Visual Studio 2017, it seems that Microsoft has changed the default behavior for loading symbols into the debugger. If a component is built with a release configuration, it skips loading the symbols.

If I open the modules window (Debug/Windows/Modules) and look for the relevant module, it says "Skipped loading symbols". I can load the symbols via the context menu.

Is it possible to change this behavior, so that the symbols are loaded automatically?

Comment: Nothing new in my version, but there are many.  The "User Code" column is relevant, if you see "No" then it won't load symbols and you can't step into that code.  Override with Tools > Options > Debugging > General > untick the "Just My Code" checkbox.  Not new behavior btw.

Comment: Thanks Hans, I did have that option selected (to my surprise). That will probably fix it, but I'm not yet 100% sure.

Comment: @Phil Jollans, What about this issue in your side? Could you load the symbols in your side now?

Comment: Yes, I think it is fixed by disabling "Just my code".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this option "Enable Just My Code" under Tools->Options->Debugging->General is enabled, the managed debugger can not load symbols for any modules that are optimized. So you could disable it, and then re-debug your app again.

In addition, you could also visit the detailed Output windows during you debug your app, you would get much more useful information from the Output window.

Visual Studio Debugger Team members also shared the possible reasons before:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e55d2f23-4803-45a9-995d-77b461e23273/skipped-loading-symbols?forum=vsdebug

Comment: I don't think it is correct to say it cannot load the symbols, but it doesn't load them automatically. If you find the component in the modules window, I think that you can load the symbols via the context menu on the component.